# Facebook login and CAS

Tags: facebook, cas

I use Jasig's CAS as a SSO solution. I now want to also support Facebook Login as part of SSO and I was thinking of building the Facebook authentication into CAS. I did not manage to find any add-on/module for this. Any clues on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this.  CAS needs to authenticates against a User database i.e. Active Directory, a user table in your MySQL Db, etc.  There is no way to connect CAS to the Facebook DB.

Another way of putting it is. CAS centralizes authentication. Facebook connect (like any OAuth systems) decentralizes authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As time goes by:

CAS may support oauth (Twitter, Facebook...) in version 3.5. As of version 3.5RC1 the oauth extension is available and seems to work.

You may have a look here:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth+client+support

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/Jasig/cas